# Вычесть многомерный массив из другого многомерного массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива

Первый: $arr1

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => aaa@gmail.com
        [ID] => 5
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => bbb@mail.ru
        [ID] => 4
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => ccc@site.ru
        [ID] => 1
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => ddd@yandex.ru
        [ID] => 24
    )

)
```

и второй: $arr2

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => aaa@gmail.com
        [ID] => 5
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => bbb@mail.ru
        [ID] => 4
    )

)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из первого многомерного массива вычесть второй многомерный массив, чтобы на выходе получить третий, содержащий значения которых нет во втором.

Вот в таком виде: $arr3

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => ccc@site.ru
        [ID] => 1
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [user_email] => ddd@yandex.ru
        [ID] => 24
    )

 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $arr1_em = array_column($arr1, 'user_email');
>
> $arr2_em = array_column($arr2, 'user_email');
>
> $arr3_em = array_diff($arr1_em, $arr2_em);  сравниваем массивы
>
> $arr3_em_keys = array_keys($arr3_em);    получаем ключи из $arr1
>   которых нет в $arr2
>
> foreach ($arr3_em_keys as $value) {   $arr3[] = $arr1[$value]; }

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array_diff_assoc($arr1,$arr2));
```

Comment: Не получается вычесть таким образом :( Данное решение выводит значения $arr2

Comment: @Владимир у меня нормально возвращает требуемый $arr3, может предоставишь свои исходные массивы в формате php?

Comment: Попробовал напрямую задать такой массив в php, все работает, а когда у меня  массивы передаются в переменную и после сравниваются выходит только вычитаемый массив... Где то я что-то не так подставил походу...  Но, на рабочем примере, я убедился, что решение тоже верное. Спасибо